# Strip out a carriage return from an environment variable - XP command line

Tags: command-line, ftp, batch-file, environment-variables, token

In a Windows XP batch file, I'm grabbing an FTP directory list and processing it with a `For /F` loop. The last token containing the file name ends up with a carriage return (0D) as the last character in the variable. Once retrieved, my attempt to use the value in the token fails because the carriage return causes my `If` statement to wrap to the beginning of the line.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,4 delims=" %%A in ('ftp -s:dir.ftp') do (
   if 'Stuff.zip'=='%%B' Set StuffDate=%%A
   )
echo Stuff.zip was saved on %StuffDate%.
```

The content to be processed is as follows:

```
ftp> dir
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for /bin/ls.
01-04-10  10:00AM                93882 Logo.jpg
02-05-10  11:01PM       <DIR>          PCODE
03-06-10  12:02PM             42333443 Saved stuff.zip
04-07-10  12:42PM             49343848 Stuff.zip
226 Transfer complete.
```

Upon examination with a hex editor, each line ends with 0D 0D 0A, instead of just 0D 0A. I'm not sure why the extra 0D is there, but I need to remove it for my program to function.

During execution when the %%B equals Stuff.zip, the `If` should look like this:

```
( if 'Stuff.zip'=='Stuff.zip' Set ReleaseDate=04-07-10 )
```

The `If` line ends up looking like this because of the CR:

```
' Set ReleaseDate=04-07-10 )  'Stuff.zip
```

The `( if 'Stuff.zip'=='Stuff.zip` gets overwritten as the 0D carriage return gets processed.

How can I get rid of an extra 0D at the end of an environment variable?

Answer (score 2):

Even if your code line looks curious, it works normally.
But in your case there is multiple ways to remove the `<CR>`.

First and simplest way - Use the batch parser, as the parser removes all `<CR>` characters after the percent expansion phase and before the special character phase.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1,4 delims=" %%A in ('ftp -s:dir.ftp') do (
   set "fileName=%%B"
   call :removeCR
   if 'Stuff.zip'=='!fileName!' Set StuffDate=%%A
   )
echo Stuff.zip was saved on %StuffDate%.
goto :eof

:removeCR
set "fileName=%fileName%"
goto :eof
```

But generally this solution could cause some problems with special characters, like exclamation marks quotes and so on.

The other way is to replace the `<CR>` with an empty string.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1,4 delims=" %%A in ('ftp -s:dir.ftp') do (
   set "fileName=%%B"
   call :removeCR
   if 'Stuff.zip'=='!fileName!' Set StuffDate=%%A
   )
echo Stuff.zip was saved on %StuffDate%.

:removeCR
set "fileName=%fileName:<CR>=%"
goto :eof
```

The `<CR>` in the line `set "fileName=%fileName:<CR>=%"` has to be changed to 0x0D with a hex-editor.
But this solution has the same special character problems like the first solution, and you can't create it with a normal text editor.

The last solution creates a single `<CR>` and uses it in the `:removeCR` function with delayed expansion.
This solution is safe against all special characters except exclamation marks.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"

for /f "tokens=1,4 delims=" %%A in ('ftp -s:dir.ftp') do (
   set "fileName=%%B"
   call :removeCR
   if 'Stuff.zip'=='!fileName!' Set StuffDate=%%A
   )
echo Stuff.zip was saved on %StuffDate%.

:removeCR
for %%a in ("!CR!") do (
    set "fileName=!fileName:%%~a=!"
)
goto :eof
```